# affordable metal tubing longer than 10ft?

Tags: metal, materials

I am working on a project where I require several lengths of metal tubing in lengths of 12ft or so, 1.25-2" diameter.  The rub is, I need it to be affordable, perhaps no more than double the cost of 2" EMT conduit.   Any suggestions for what materials to pursue ? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "shop for me" question. Please see https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions for more information.

Comment: For heavens' sake.   I need a material like this, I don't know if it exists, and I would like to know.    I will try re-wording the question and maybe it won't be so problematic.

Comment: I had similar issue recently 20’ lengths were not to be found locally. I used emt couplings they are not very attractive.  Google shows some dealers with 20’ emt but I can imagine shipping would be awful.  For railings I prefer threaded pipe since the tees and elbows can be planned to align with mounting locations

Comment: Wow, yeah, I hate to think of shipping on a 20ft piece of ... anything.   "Planned to align" if you thread the pipe yourself, you mean ?

Comment: The big box stores will cut and thread the pieces you need. Carefully plan the run of the rail you may only need a couple pieces custom length.

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/131519251593191091/.

Comment: Your edit changed the cost to no more than half the cost of emt  I found emt to be the cheapest pipe available

Comment: My mistake, @Kris, I edited it; I meant "double the cost of EMT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of material?  Purpose?  You're leaving alot out here.

Steel yards typically carry 20' or 24' sticks of various profiles, including tubing.  Price will depend on size, etc.

Comment: Thanks for offering help.  For a railing.    The unimpressive strength of EMT conduit would suffice.   Other than that, as I said: 12ft lengths, 1.25-2" diameter, no more than double the cost of 2" EMT conduit.  What other desiderata would be helpful ?Thanks.

Comment: Called steel yard.  Welded steel tubing (apparently there's a weld bead along the edge, visible but smooth, so unnoticeable if painted) is only about $30 for a 2" diameter 12ft stick, 65mil wall thickness (iow, a lot less than double the cost of EMT).    Perfect I think.   Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: There's something odd going on with permissions: I'm actually able to edit your post - doesn't seem right.

Comment: Yea, welded steel tubing will be cheaper.  There will be a ridge on the seam inside, but the outside will be smooth.  The other alternative is DOM (Drawn Over Mandrel) tubing, which will be more expensive, and likely heavier wall then you need.  But no seam.  That's what is typically used for roll bars, race car frames, etc.

Comment: Yeah, DOM seems overkill, though maybe I could get away with painting it and still have it look decent (this is for an interior loft railing), which is probably not the case for the welded stuff.   Thanks for the pointer.  Any idea why I'm able to edit your answer, tat isn't right is it ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be able to edit anything but your own stuff at this point.